# Django Listview classmethod

Tags: python, django

In django >2 .0  have Handler class ListView

**my code:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views 

urlpatterns = [
    # post views
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    # path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
```

**In source code django:**

```
 @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        """Main entry point for a request-response process."""
        ...........

        def view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            self = cls(**initkwargs)
          ...........................
        update_wrapper(view, cls.dispatch, assigned=())
        return view
```

**views.post_list** - simple function in module views

**views.PostListView.as_view()** - module(views)-> class inherited from 
ListView(PostList)-> class method from ListView - as_view()

Why is it written with brackets ?

Comment: Because `.as_view` is does not handle the requests. It returns a `view` function that will handle the requests.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it written with brackets?

Because the `MyListView.as_view` will *not* handle the requests. Indeed, this function will *return* the `view` function, and *that* `view` function is the function that will act as a handler for the view.

The `.as_view()` will make some checks, for example that you did not pass a `get` or `post` parameter to the `.as_view`, etc.

When a request is then triggered, the view will be executed, this will construct a `ListView` object with `cls(**initkwargs)`, then call `.setup(request, args, kwargs)` to set the `request`, `args` and `kwargs` objects, and eventually use `.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` to let the class-view handle the request, and return the HTTP response.

Comment: it mean this as_view() -> excute - > any returned function pass to path function ?  Thank you

Comment: @Mikhail: the `.as_view` is *not* executed when you make a request. It is used as a "preparation" step. The `view` function is executed per request. It can serve multiple paths yes.

Comment: "preparation" step. Thank you